# Phyloseq: relative abundance otu-table and metadata do not match

Tags: phyloseq

I am relatively new to phyloseq and I struggle to obtain a relative abundance otu-table acceptable for input to [siamcat R code for meta-analysis](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/SIAMCAT/inst/doc/SIAMCAT_meta.html).

```
# this works: from qza to phyloseq object
ps<-qza_to_phyloseq(
  features="all-table.qza",
  tree="rooted-tree.qza",
  taxonomy = "all-taxonomy.qza",
  metadata = "metafinal.tsv"
)

# import metadata
metadata <- read_tsv("metafinal.tsv")

# 30 overlap of the metadata-sample_id with ps, 115 only in metadata
gplots::venn(list(metadata=metadata$sample_id, features=sample_names(ps))

# works: from phyloseq object to relative abundance otu table
table(tax_table(ps)[, "Phylum"])
ps_rel_abund <- transform_sample_counts(ps, function(x){x / sum(x)})
ps_phylum_rel <- tax_glom(ps_rel_abund, "Phylum")
taxa_names(ps_phylum_rel) <- tax_table(ps_phylum_rel)[, "Phylum"]
rel_table <- as(otu_table(ps_phylum_rel), "matrix")

# column names and sample_id are 100% the same
colnames(rel_table)
metadata$sample_id

# 100% overlap:
gplots::venn(list(metadata=metadata$sample_id, featuretable=colnames(rel_table)))

# check that metadata and feature agree
stopifnot(all(colnames(rel_table) == metadata$sample_id))
```

and here I get an error message: all(colnames(rel_table) == metadata$sample_id) is not TRUE
and the following [siamcat code](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/SIAMCAT/inst/doc/SIAMCAT_meta.html) is not working at all.

my `metadata[1:5, 1:5]`:
sample_id  absolute_filepath  study experiment_acce… study_title
                                 
1 SRR8547628 $PWD/Chen_2020_da… Chen… SRX5349649       Dissection of c…
2 SRR8547629 $PWD/Chen_2020_da… Chen… SRX5349648       Dissection of c…
3 SRR8547630 $PWD/Chen_2020_da… Chen… SRX5349647       Dissection of c…
4 SRR8547631 $PWD/Chen_2020_da… Chen… SRX5349646       Dissection of c…
5 SRR8547632 $PWD/Chen_2020_da… Chen… SRX5349645       Dissection of c…

my `rel-table[1:5, 1:5]`:
SRR5092146 SRR5092147 SRR5092148  SRR5092149
Phragmoplastophyta          0  0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
Vertebrata                  0  0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
Apicomplexa                 0  0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
Ascomycota                  0  0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
Campilobacterota            0  0.2465222 0.01166882 0.004337051
SRR5092150
Phragmoplastophyta 0.00000000
Vertebrata         0.00000000
Apicomplexa        0.00000000
Ascomycota         0.00000000
Campilobacterota   0.02106281

`nrow(metadata)`= 154
`ncol(rel_table)`= 154

Please, why is it not working? I tried for weeks now and I can't make the code run properly ...

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wondering, why you have perfect overlap between sample IDs in your metadata and in your feature table, but why

```
stopifnot(all(colnames(rel_table) == metadata$sample_id))
```

returns `FALSE`.

I think it is because your samples seem to be in a different order. The first five samples in your metadata are:

```
SRR8547628
SRR8547629
SRR8547630
SRR8547631
SRR8547632
```

and the first five samples in your feature table are:

```
SRR5092146
SRR5092147
SRR5092148
SRR5092149
SRR5092150
```

Try

```
stopifnot(all(colnames(rel_table) %in% metadata$sample_id))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I did reorder the metadata, so they were correctly in the same order as the relative abundance table, but no, it didn't help at all.
My final solution was then to add rownames(metadata) <- sample_names(ps)